# how to implement undo facility in fabricjs?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to implement undo facility in fabricjs, I searilized object and store its content into javascript `array` , but when I load it back into using `loadFromJson()` also fire `object:add` event, so is there any way to fire this event when I load back from history.